# Htaccess URL Rewriting 2 Different cases But Same URL Structure

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I am following a url structure for my site
ex url structure is :

```
http://www.example.com/service-name-1
http://www.example.com/service-name-2
```

etc
This is case 1
Now check my htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-\s0-9]+)$ service_detail.php?seo=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

my htaccess is perfectly rewriting url and redirecting to service_detail.php page (I have no problem with it)

Now 2nd case is i have some other urls which have physical pages Example

```
http://www.example.com/contact-us.php
http://www.example.com/openings.php
```

if i remove .php from the url then htaccess thought that this is a redirect url and it redirected to service_detail.php page

instead of that i want a rule in which i i wright if contact-us OR openings is present in url then it will redirect to contact-us.php page OR openings.php page

but without.php extension
LIKE this

```
http://www.example.com/contact-us
http://www.example.com/openings
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-\s0-9]+).php$ $1.php [L,QSA]`, its been a long time since ive done more then `.* index.php` ;p

Comment: Thx buddy .. but it is not working

Comment: Thx buddy .. it is working

Comment: cool, did you put it *above* the other one?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone The rule you posted above will probably cause an **infinite loop error** as it rewrites `/file.php` to itself `/file.php` I am sure OP didn't test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your pattern `^([A-Za-z-\s0-9]+)$` matches `contact-us` and all other similar requests that don't exist as file and directorie on your server. To solve this :

Add the following right bellow `RewriteEngine on`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

This will rewrite your extension-less php requests to their original destination ie : `/contact-us` to `/contact-us.php` .